# Company of Heroes balance

Tags: company-of-heroes

I recently got Company of Heroes and the two expansion packs. I have heard that CoH: Opposing Fronts pretty much broke the balance that existed in the original. Does anyone know if the gameplay has been rebalanced with the release of CoH: Tales of Valor?

Comment: Questions about balance are usually questions that are [not based on an actual problem](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). See ["Why did They design it that way, anyway?", and why do we allow or disallow these?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-these) for more information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It broke the balance when it initially came out but that has long since been fixed in patches. All of the races have advantages and disadvantages as well as different ways of playing them. The tales of valor units give options rather than any particular advantage, and people choose not to use them even when they are available.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is not closed by this date I will add that the patching has not ceased.  Further unbalanced remainded specially in matches between:

```
German vs British [halftrack + pioneer rush ; now British infantry does much more damage to the halftrack]
Americans vs Panzer elite [Infantry command and heavy rangers vs anythin that PE would throw; now the Americans cannot have a blob that can match PE without using weapon support or vehicles]
```

You should note however that the game is now scarcely played, meaning that the more balanced stats that the game sees are not as significant as before. There is however, a very effective response to any rush strategy

Answer (score 0):

I think that CoH: Tales of Valor mostly added more game modes.  The main changes it makes to the game balance is to add additional optional units that can only be used by Tales of Valor players, and are not available to 'mere' CoH: Opposing Fronts players.  Since I don't think that letting some people use some units and not others adds much balance, I'm gonna vote no.